# What I need to set up in a Gatsby Plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, graphql, gatsby

I am stuck in a Gatsby tutorial. I installed the required plugin  (gatsby-transformer-remark) via NPM, I can see in package.json, it is installed. 
I setted up gatsby-config.js, should be fine. If I try to access these new methods in Graphiql playground, doesn't show up, I cant make the query, provided by this plugin.

After plugin install I restarted the devserver, I tried the config file from the tutorial (just make sure not a typo), refreshed graphiql plaground, reboot pc, really everything.

```
//config.js 
module.exports = {

  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-sass",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "src",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    "gatsby-transformer-remark",
  ],
}
```

If the plugin works properly, the in the graphiql playground I can write query to access, and then parse .md files.

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: The worst thing, no any error...

Comment: Hi there, is the markdown file stored in `src/`? otherwise, you'd have to add another instance of `gatsby-source-filesystem` with `path` set to wherever you store your `.md`

Comment: @DerekNguyen .md files are in the src/blog/ that might be the problem?

Comment: @ÁdámSzalóczi it should be fine then, what query did you try in the graphql playground?